# C++ Access Violation Error when setting value

Tags: c++, malloc, access-violation

can someone explain to me why this code get's an access violation error when the last line runs but not when h_A[0] is set to 100?

```
int nx = 16384;
int ny = 16384;
int nxy = nx*ny;
int nBytes = nxy * sizeof(int);

int *h_A;
h_A = (int *) malloc(nBytes);
h_A[0] = 100;

int *h_B;
h_B = (int *) malloc(nBytes);
h_B[0] = 100;
```

The error is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01079554 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Edit:

Here is the **solution** thanks to @owacoder

```
int nx = 1238;//8;
int ny = 16384;//6;
int nxy = nx*ny;
int nBytes = nxy * sizeof(int);


int *h_A;
if ((h_A = (int *) malloc(nBytes)) == NULL){
    printf("Malloc failed...\n");
    return 0;
} else {
    initialInt (h_A, nxy); // Fills matrix with numbers
}


int *h_B;
if ((h_B = (int *) malloc(nBytes)) == NULL){
    printf("Malloc failed...\n");
    return 0;
} else {
    initialInt (h_B, nxy); // Fills matrix with numbers
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't check whether `malloc` succeeded.

Comment: Any particular reason you feel the need to attempt to allocate about 1GB of memory at a time to then set a value that would fit in char or is this completely out of context? As mentioned your second malloc is likely failing ... if I had to guess it's because you're consuming more than the addressable space for a 32-bit process.

Comment: @AJG85 it's for a class. We're supposed to use large numbers to test the difference between CUDA and CPU computations.

Answer (score 5):

The second allocation failed, while the first did not. (i.e. `malloc` returned `NULL`, out of memory) You should put error checking for an out of memory condition in your code.

Comment: Thank you! That was just what I needed.